# How to display an array returned from server side inside a component using angular?

Tags: php, arrays, angular, http

I am using PHP with Angular (Version 5) to get data from MySQL. I have this php class:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

require_once("./serverConnection.php");

class affiliatePartner
{
    public function getPartners(){
        global $conn;
        $result = array();
        $getPartners = "SELECT partner_name FROM partner";
        $execGetPartners = $conn->prepare($getPartners);
        $execGetPartners->execute();
        $result = $execGetPartners->fetchAll();
        return json_encode($result);
    }
}
?>
```

Then I have a php file to run the function:

```
<?php
    require_once('affiliatePartner.php');

    $aff = new affiliatePartner;

    $result = $aff->getPartners();
    echo $result;
?>
```

When I run the file, I can see the json array normally:

> [{"partner_name":"Udemy","0":"Udemy"},{"partner_name":"Nike","0":"Nike"}]

Now in the client-side, I added into the app.module.ts:

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
```

And import it into imports:

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
```

And in the component:

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private http: Http){
    this.createForms();
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.http.get('http://aff.local/getPartners.php').subscribe(
            data =>{
                this.results = data['result'];
                console.log(this.results);
            },
            error =>{
                console.log('error');
            }
        )
 }
```

Now at the console, I am seeing `Undefined` as a result:

[image]

So how can I display the name of partners in the console ?

**Edit**

When I logged data I got this:

[image]

But I just need to display:

Udemy

Nike

Comment: If you log just data what's your result in console?

Comment: I can see an array but I just need to display : Udemy, Nike. Look at the edit t the end of my question.

Comment: Try to log just data, not data['results']

Comment: @GianlucaParis check the edit

Comment: Yes I did that just data

Answer (score 0):

Result Object is not present in your json so remove it and access directly. I'm just showing how to iterate through the array of objects, same loop you need to perform in html. Make sure you have rxjs library imported.

```
//import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

ngOnInit(){
this.http.get('http://aff.local/getPartners.php').map(repsonse => response.json()).subscribe(
        data =>{
            this.results = data;
            var res = this.results.map(data=>{
            console.log(data. partner_name)
            })
        },
        error =>{
            console.log('error');
        }
    )
 }
```

Comment: Yes but I just need to display the name: Like Udemy, Nike, I don't want the full array properties

Comment: No I had the following error: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at SafeSubscriber.eval`

Answer (score 0):

Try to consume rest like this:

```
 this.http.get('http://aff.local/getPartners.php')
   .map(response => response.json).catch(error => console.log(error)
   .subscribe(partners: Partner[] => this.results = partners);
```

One more thing you have to do is to create class or interface Partner with appropiate fields as in json.
Of course if you don't make it strongly typed do like this (but it's not recommended in typescript):

```
 this.http.get('http://aff.local/getPartners.php')
   .map(response => response.json).catch(error => console.log(error)
   .subscribe(partners => this.results = partners);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting `undefined` because data is the json received, and as you've shown, it is an array of objects. json arrays don't have any result property.

You can put data directly into your result variable, and you can enforce the content of what you receive with types.

Here what you can do. First create a model of your data `partner.ts`:

```
export class Partner {
    partner_name: string;
    // other properties here
}
```

Then modify your component as follow:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    results: Partner[];


    ngOnInit(){
        this.http.get<Partner[]>('http://aff.local/getPartners.php').subscribe(
        data =>{
            this.results = data;
            console.log(this.results);
        },
        error =>{
            console.log('error');
        })
    }
}
```

Finally, in `home.component.html` display your elements:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let res of results">
       {{ res.partner_name }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I got the following error: `Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1.`

Comment: Try to add `header('Content-Type: application/json');` in your php file